# In DataGridView using the CellMouseDoubleClick and detecting when someone clicked the Header

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

In my DataGridView control, I'd like the user to double click a row and fetch relevant information.

Here is my code: (**EDIT**)

```
private void dataGridView1_CellMouseDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex != -1)
    {
        int studentID = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1[0, e.RowIndex].Value);
        StudentInformation addForm = new StudentInformation(studentID);
        addForm.ShowDialog();
    }            
}
```

The problem is when someone double clicks the header (and I only found this bug by accident!) an exception fires. I don't want handle anything when the users double clicks the header.

How can I detect when the header has been clicked?

Thank you!

**EDIT** 
It seems that header have a RowIndex of -1. Is this the best way to check, or is this a dirty hack?

Answer (score 1):

Check if the datagridview.SelectedRows.Count > 0, this will help you also when no rows are selected

```
private void dataGridView1_CellMouseDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && dataGridView.SelectedRows.Count>0)
    {
        int studentID = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1[0, e.RowIndex].Value);
        StudentInformation addForm = new StudentInformation(studentID);
        addForm.ShowDialog();
    }            
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private void dgvDataGridView_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (sender != null && e != null && ((MouseEventArgs)e).Y <= ((DataGridView)sender).Rows[0].Height)
        return; //Double click on Header
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void radgvAreaAdmin_CellDoubleClick(object sender, GridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
      if (e.Row.Index <= -1)
           //Do your code inside in it.
}
```

e.rowindex may vary with your focus. But if you use e.row.index, it would always be -1 when we click on Column header of grid. If you want to ignore the double click in header, just use 'return' after the if-condition.